# In Spring MVC, @ResponseBody return null when add self defined Annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web

For example,

```
@Authority
@RequestMapping(value="/list",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String listNewEnterprises(HttpServletRequest request) {    
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    //do something
    Object o;
    try {
        json.put("result", "success");
        json.put("value", o);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(json);// can print the json value
    return json.toString();
}
```

All work well before adding `@Authority`, but once added `@Authority`, the ajax get Null.

My `@Authority` is used to authorize user's right to access the method, which is intercepted by extending `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.

The `spring-mvc.xml` is configured as:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:interceptors>      
     <bean class="com.sjd.annotation.AuthorityAnnotationInterceptor"></bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

========================================

My AuthorityAnnotationInterceptor class is implemented as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class AuthorityAnnotationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    HandlerMethod handler2 = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    Authority auth = handler2.getMethodAnnotation(Authority.class);
    if (null == auth) {
        return true;
    }
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    logger.debug(url);
    if (null == url) {
        return false;
    }
    HttpSession session  = request.getSession();
    String userAuthority = (String) session.getAttribute("authority");
    //boolean hasAuthority = AuthorityHelper.hasAuthority(userAuthority,url, auth.type());
    boolean hasAuthority = true;
    if (hasAuthority) {
        logger.debug("pass");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("fail");
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, let's see what `AuthorityAnnotationInterceptor` does.

Comment: try `@PreAuthorize` , if this works then u can be sure that `@Authority` has problem in implementation. and please provide code for your `@Authority` cass

Comment: Thank you for your comments, AuthorityAnnotationInterceptor class has been added. 
@SotiriosDelimanolis,@LynAs